# Create subfolder when zipping

Tags: zip, directory

I have file A, B, C

with only the `zip` command, I would like to create a zip xxx.zip with this structure:

- xxx folder:

  - A
  - B
  - C

Actually what I am doing, because I have found no way in the zip handbook is

```
mkdir xxx
cp A B C xxx
zip -r xxx.zip xxx
```

Is there anyway to prevent the `cp`?

Comment: What platform are you on? On my machine the zip command just takes a list of files: `zip xxx.zip A B C`. But I'm working on a Mac.

Comment: Also, you might try `man zip` if you're on linux/UNIX. Or `zip /H` on windows (I think).

Comment: I am on make. But the problem is not to take a list of files, the problem is to have the right structure in the .zip file.

Comment: I have tried man zip... and I have found no way to do what I need."I have found no way in the zip handbook "

Answer (score 0):

In a other list some one send me a system more efficient that cp : link.

`mkdir xxx
ln A B C xxx
zip -r xxx.zip xxx`